# gotoxy command got skipped in pascal

Tags: pascal

I'm working on a school assignment. In line 87 and down, the gotoxy didn't work but the code does. Here's the cropped part of the code.

```
gotoxy(32,24); write(' _______________________________________________ ');
gotoxy(32,25); write('|                 PESANAN ANDA                  |');
gotoxy(32,26); writeln('|_______________________________________________|');
gotoxy(20,27); writeln('     ', nama,' ');
gotoxy(20,27); writeln('     Rp.', jumlah,',-');
gotoxy(20,28); write('     Porsi: ');
gotoxy(20,28); writeln(porsi2);
gotoxy(20,29); write('     Jenis: ');
gotoxy(20,29); writeln(lokasi);
gotoxy(20,30); write('     Total: ');
gotoxy(20,29); writeln('Rp.', total,',-');
readln;
end;
```

end.

[When I compile and run the program, the bottom part looks like this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnaKS.png)

I've been searching for a similar problem with its solution in this and other forms and I didn't get the answer.

Comment: Probably, you should not be using `writeln` in combination with `gotoxy` - just `write`.

Comment: the previous line works with writeln though. Also, when I put write, the "Soto Bandung" text shifted next to the box.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you

```
  write(ScreenWidth, 'x', ScreenHeight);
```

you'll probably see `80x25`. A `gotoxy()` outside this range doesn't work as one might expect.